# Creating bitmap from string path

Tags: android, performance, time, bitmap

So i'm creating bitmap, using this code:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
options.inMutable = true;
return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, options);
```

My problem is, why is it taking so much time creating it on some mobile ?
is there any way to create bitmap without wasting a lot of time waiting ?
Does any guys meet this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use a **scaled down** version of image so that you can avoid memory as well as execution time wastage

2) Try processing the bitmaps asynchronously.

You can refer to http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Try Below Code Snippet:

```
public static Bitmap decodeFile(String photoPath){
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, options);

        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inDither = false;
        options.inPurgeable = true;
        options.inInputShareable = true;
        options.inPreferQualityOverSpeed = true;

        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, options);
}
```